# Difference between IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY and IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

What's meaning of IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY and IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY respectively? I'm now puzzled by their concepts. Thanks in advance.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY is used for [OS authentication](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10574/authentication.htm#i1007520)

IDENTIFIED GLOBALLY is used for [OID authentication](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10574/authentication.htm#i1006269)(also known as EUS)

Both of these mean that password management is done outside the database.